# Extension Utility for invoking on a control's thread

Tags: c#, user-interface, multithreading

I have attempted to create a one-size-fits all utility for invoking on the main thread.  Below is what I have come up with - are there any problems with doing it this way?  Is checking for both IsHandleCreated and IsDisposed redundant?  When it is Disposed, will IsHandleCreated be set to false? (since that is the default value of the bool)

```
    public static void InvokeMain(this Control Source, Action Code)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Source == null || !Source.IsHandleCreated || Source.IsDisposed) { return; }
            if (Source.InvokeRequired)
            {
                Source.BeginInvoke(Code);
            }
            else
            {
                Code.Invoke();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }    
    }
```

Thanks in advanced!
William

Comment: The only thing that might bite you is if `InvokeRequired` is true, the call becomes asynchronous whereas if it is false the call is completed synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering from the top of my head, so excuse me if there are any errors;

You should not trap exceptions unless you are expecting them and know how to react in the case they are thrown, if that is not the case is better to leave them bubble up until they reach a common Application error handler where you log it/show a message or whatever.

Also returning in case the control is null / not initialized means you will be hiding a possible bug, why would you want to do that? I'd very much prefer the call failing rather than returning without doing anything, if you want to prevent having an NullPointer exception then you should be raising an exception yourself (as ArgumentNullException) if the control is null

```
public static void Invoke(this Control control, Action action)
{
    if (control == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("control");

    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        control.Invoke(action);
        return;
    }

    action();
}

public static T Invoke<T>(this Control control, Func<T> action)
{
    if (control == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("control");

    if (control.InvokeRequired)
        return (T)control.Invoke(action);

    return action();
}
```